# It's not a method, its not a variable, its not a property, what is it?

Tags: c#

I ran across something I don't understand today. Consider the following snippet:

```
public class EventStreamCollection<TKey, TValue>
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> _dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    private readonly Func<TKey, TValue> _factory;
    public EventStreamCollection(Func<TKey, TValue> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public TValue this[TKey key] => _dictionary.GetOrAdd(key, _factory);
}
```

What is this line

```
public TValue this[TKey key] => _dictionary.GetOrAdd(key, _factory);
```

It has no name that I can see. If it did, I guess it would be a property? What is it and how does it work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a read-only, [indexer property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/).

Indexers use `this` as the name. It allows you to support square brackets on an instance of your your type.

Using the `=>` syntax, it makes it read-only.

Comment: It allows you to support square brackets on an instance variable of your type.

Comment: @PhilipSmith updated

Comment: And it's possible only with C#6 or higher